# Windows 7 Remote Desktop stopped crash

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a problem with the remote desktop connection on Windows 7 professional 64 bits (6.1 version 7601).

When I type the password of the server and click on connect button, it crashs.

I know that if the printers checkbox is checked, it causes this type of problems but I disable all local resources.

Here is the dump files :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xvthjbldyr1ncl2/LocalDumps.zip?dl=0

Thanks.

Comment: download [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v81q3got2ts52x6/WER_remoteDesktop_full.reg) from my Dropbox, make a double click on the .reg file to import it. When the RDP client crashes, [Windows Error Reporting Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) creates a dmp file under C:\Localdumps. upload the file, compresssed as zip post the link here. I take a look at the dump maybe I can see the cause.
After you generated the dumps, import [this regfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ixfw7kbjm32ach/WER_remoteDesktop_uninstall.reg) to stop the dump creation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I edited my question, you can find the dump files under the dropbox link. Many thanks.

Comment: I can't get the debug symbols so I can't see any details.

Comment: Thanks again, I think it is the time to format the pc or to pass to Windows 10.

Comment: debug symbols are now online and I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debug symbols are now online and [I see in Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/DefragTools-136-Debugging-User-Mode-Crash-Dumps-Part-2#time=04m52s) that the `BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll` from `CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack` causes your crash:

```
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_HEAPS_CORRUPTED_HEAP_BLOCK_EXCEPTION_RAISED_FOR_PROBING (c)
Exception raised while verifying the heap block.
This situation happens if we really cannot determine any particular
type of corruption for the block. For instance you will get this if
during a heap free operation you pass an address that points to a
non-accessible memory area.
This can also happen for double free situations if we do not find the
block among full page heap blocks and we probe it as a light page heap block. 
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000025701000, Heap handle used in the call. 
Arg2: f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0, Heap block involved in the operation. 
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Size of the heap block. 
Arg4: 00000000c0000005, Reserved. 


DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=000000000d65cee0 rbx=0000000000000001 rcx=000007fffff94000
rdx=000000000000fffd rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=000000000000000c
rip=000007fee9f9a668 rsp=000000001a20d9a0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=000000001a203000  r9=0000000040010006 r10=0000000000000000
r11=000000001a20c528 r12=0000000000000000 r13=000000000000005d
r14=f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
verifier!VerifierStopMessage+0x1f0:
000007fe`e9f9a668 cc              int     3
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
verifier!VerifierStopMessage+1f0
000007fe`e9f9a668 cc              int     3

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fee9f9a668 (verifier!VerifierStopMessage+0x00000000000001f0)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_AVRF

PROCESS_NAME:  mstsc.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {AUSNAHME}  Haltepunkt  Im Quellprogramm wurde ein Haltepunkt erreicht.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - Mindestens ein Argument ist ung ltig.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  524b5b3d

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  6.3.9600.16415

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.1.7601.24000 (win7sp1_ldr.171231-1547)

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
OS_LOCALE:  FRA

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n300]
    Type:   [@APPLICATION_FAULT_STRING]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Omit
    Data:   Add
            String: [BREAKPOINT]
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [Unspecified]
    Frame:  [0]

    ID:     [0n92]
    Type:   [AVRF]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x2fe0]
    TID:    [0x1c98]
    Frame:  [0] : verifier!VerifierStopMessage

BUGCHECK_STR:  BREAKPOINT_AVRF

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  BREAKPOINT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007fee9f994f2 to 000007fee9f9a668

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`1a20d9a0 000007fe`e9f994f2 : 00000000`1a20ea28 000007fe`e9f91988 000007fe`fd649270 000007fe`e9f91610 : verifier!VerifierStopMessage+0x1f0
00000000`1a20da50 000007fe`e9fb5863 : 000007fe`e9fb6604 00000000`1a20e9f0 000007fe`fd470000 00000000`1a20e9f0 : verifier!AVrfpDphReportCorruptedBlock+0x32a
00000000`1a20db10 00000000`76d67398 : 00000000`1a20dc70 00000000`1a20dc40 00000000`00000000 00000000`76d58468 : verifier!_chkstk+0xf3
00000000`1a20db40 00000000`76d7bf9d : 00000000`1a210000 00000000`1a20e9f0 00000000`1a20e9f0 000007fe`e9fde0fc : ntdll!_C_specific_handler+0x8c
00000000`1a20dbb0 00000000`76d504ca : 00000000`1a210000 00000000`01001002 000007fe`00001950 00000000`02991710 : ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
00000000`1a20dbe0 00000000`76d7b63e : 00000000`1a20e7b0 00000000`1a20e2c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x45a
00000000`1a20e2c0 000007fe`e9f96be1 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e
00000000`1a20e9f0 000007fe`e9f98b87 : 00000000`25701000 f0f0f0f0`f0f0f0f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : verifier!AVrfpDphFindBusyMemoryNoCheck+0x91
00000000`1a20ea50 00000000`76dd4a14 : 00000000`25700000 00000000`1a20f2e0 00000000`01001002 00000000`00000000 : verifier!AVrfDebugPageHeapSize+0x5b
00000000`1a20ea90 00000000`76d9427f : 00000000`25700000 00000000`00000000 00000000`25700000 f0f0f0f0`f0f0f0f0 : ntdll!RtlDebugSizeHeap+0x34
00000000`1a20eae0 000007fe`e9fb093f : 00000000`00000000 f0f0f0f0`f0f0f0f0 00000000`02a80000 000007fe`d87e9a63 : ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0xd26f
00000000`1a20eb30 000007fe`d87eed84 : 00000000`25700000 00000000`00000000 f0f0f0f0`f0f0f0f0 00000000`76c11a00 : verifier!AVrfpHeapFree+0x57
00000000`1a20ebc0 00000000`25700000 : 00000000`00000000 f0f0f0f0`f0f0f0f0 00000000`76c11a00 00000000`00000000 : BLEtokenCredentialProvider+0xed84
00000000`1a20ebc8 00000000`00000000 : f0f0f0f0`f0f0f0f0 00000000`76c11a00 00000000`00000000 000007fe`d87e6b46 : 0x25700000


SYMBOL_NAME:  bletokencredentialprovider+ed84

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: BLEtokenCredentialProvider

IMAGE_NAME:  BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4f686c3b

STACK_COMMAND:  .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  X64_BREAKPOINT_AVRF_bletokencredentialprovider+ed84

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  80000003

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll


FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:breakpoint_avrf_80000003_bletokencredentialprovider.dll!unknown

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {2a6d23c0-cb20-73ec-3d92-f208d9f741cc}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0:020> lmvm BLEtokenCredentialProvider
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
000007fe`d87e0000 000007fe`d885d000   BLEtokenCredentialProvider T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack\BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll
    Image name: BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Tue Mar 20 12:38:35 2012 (4F686C3B)
    CheckSum:         000826D1
    ImageSize:        0007D000
    File version:     2.1.63.0
    Product version:  2.1.63.0
```

Look for an update and if there is no one, remove this tool.

Comment: Bravo!  I cleaned a buggy tool from my machine *and* learned how to debug these things myself.  Excellent work, @magicandre1981